# Problemas con metodo en java no imprime correctamente

Tags: java

Tengo un problea que cuando imprime todo me marca cero lo siguiente es el principio de el programa y es donde me marca error segun por que tiene que ir un string y aun que le cambie de tipo me continua dando error de ante mano les agradeceria que me puedan ayudar gracias :,D

```
introducir el código aquí
import java.io.*;
public class Carrera{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    int Segundos = 0;
 ////////////error en las dos lineas siguientes
    AutoRadioControl A = new AutoRadioControl();
    AutoRadioControl B = new AutoRadioControl("Him",2,100);
```

///////////////////////Metodos

```
public  AutoRadioControl(String Nombre,double Bateria,int Velocidad,int Distancia1){
    Tipo = 1;
    Nombre = "Black Hat";
    CapBateria = 100;
    Bateria = CapBateria;
    Velocidad = 8;
    Distancia=Distancia1;
}
//C.COMPLETO
public AutoRadioControl(String Nom, int Tip, double CB,double Bateria1,int Velocidad1){
    Tipo = Tip;
    Nombre =Nom;
    Bateria =   Bateria1;
    Velocidad1 = Velocidad1;
    CapBateria = CB;
}
```

Comment: Si estás sobrecargando el constructor, no tienes una definición que cubra ninguno de los dos casos que indicas en tu código. CUando no envías parámetros, cómo deberían inicializarse los atributos? Y cuando sólo mandas un String y dos enteros?

Answer (score 0):

Si tu error es en la línea:

> AutoRadioControl B = new AutoRadioControl("Him",2,100);

Es porque no tienes ningún constructor con tres argumentos, tienes con cuatro y cinco argumentos. Después de eso ya tendrías que revisar el tipo de dato por argumento.

Si tuvieras un constructor como el siguiente, no tendrías ese problema al llamarlo de esa manera:

```
String miNombre;
int miBateria, miVelocidad;

public  AutoRadioControl(String Nombre, int  Bateria,int Velocidad){
    this.miNombre = Nombre;
    this.miBateria = Bateria;
    this.miVelocidad = Velocidad;
}
```